# Contrapositve issues

Tags: logic

I'm currently reading logic and have some issues with the contrapositve of this statement:

The textbook says:

> If $n>0$ and $4n−1$ is prime, then $n$ is odd

I understand the contrapositive thinking (I think!) $P\to Q$ becomes with this logic $\neg Q\to\neg P$

Therefore in my mind this statement should be:

> If n is even, then $0>n$ and $4n-1$ is not prime.

But this does not even make sense. Are there any rules I'm missing?

Comment: Changed odd to even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple of rules. Let me write your sentences with parentheses:

> If (($n>0$) and ($4n-1$ is prime)), then ($n$ is odd)$.

Ok, now we know what $P$ and $Q$ are more clearly. So, we can reverse them and get

> If (not ($n$ is odd)), then (not (($n>0$) and ($4n-1$ is prime)))

This should be clear, since I just wrote "not" in front of both sentences. Now let's examine the two parts:

- not ($n$ is odd). Well, that one's easy. $n$ is not odd if and only if it is even, so this changes to "$n$ is even" and we are done.
- not (($n>0$) and ($4n-1$ is prime)). Hmm. This is a composite statement, two statements joined with **and**. You probably know the rule for that: $\neg(P\land Q)$ is the same as $\neg P\lor \neg Q$ (DeMorgan's law), so the original expression becomes

  > ((not $n>0$) **OR** (not ($4n-1$ is prime)))

  which then simpliy simplifies down to

  > ($n\leq 0$ **OR** ($4n-1$ is composite)).

So the total reversal is equivalent to

> If $n$ is even, then $n\leq 0$ or $4n-1$ is composite.

Comment: Thank you. However, if I try it out it does not seem to appear true!

If n = 2 then it is not bigger than 0 but it is not a composite either:
4(2) 8 - 1 = 7 which is a prime.

Am I missing some other crucial points?

Comment: @mathnotsogenious Well, the statement isn't true. What is important is that both the statement and its contrapositive are **equally true**, i.e. either they are both false or both true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $\lnot$($n>0$ and $4n-1$ is prime) is ($n\leq 0$ *or* $4n-1$ is composite), not ($n\leq 0$ *and* $4n-1$ is composite).

Note that both the original statement and the contrapositive statement is false, as evidenced by, for instance, $n=2$ (at least they agree, which is the main point).